# Unable to DROP Index (Sybase) on a table from Java Code

Tags: java, exception, indexing, sybase

I have a Stored Procedure which drops index on a particular table in the DB. This SP when executed from Database console works fine without errors.

When I use JDBC to execute the SP using a Callable Statement, it gives an SQL exception and says the index cannot be dropped.

When checked on the database, the indexes are dropped too.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_drop_idx as
    BEGIN

    DROP INDEX sp_close_1.XPKusr1
    DROP INDEX sp_close_1.ilxuser22
    DROP INDEX sp_close_1.indx_billid1
    DROP INDEX sp_close_1.cycle_ind
    END 
    GO
```

This SP is called within another SP, let's call that **outerSP** from the java code using plain JDBC call.

```
    cb = conn.prepareCall("{call outerSP}");
    s = cb.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        num = (Integer)rs.getInt(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple change in the SP :

For every index we used an IF condition -

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sysindexes where id = object_id('sp_close_1') and name ='XPKusr1')
        DROP INDEX sp_close_1.XPKusr1
```